# Resetting cumulative Sum but having precedent val

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in PySpark containing order data (order number, customerId,month_first_date active_in_month,active_previous_month).
Active In Month is set to True if the User had at least 1 order during the month and active previous month is basically the lag of active In Month.
MonthFirstDate is only used as an orderby key when using partitions

I need to calculate the number of consecutive months a customer was active (Active In Month is True) for each customer . I want the sum to reset if the customer was inactive (months_active is False) but the difficulty comes from the fact i want the row where a customer becomes inactive to still have the value of the runningSum i can already calculate the cumSum using groups that increment whenever a customer goes from active to inactive. I'll provide an example.

| customer_id | Month | year | active_in_month | active_previous_month | ConsecMonthsActiveTarget | CumSumWithGroups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 2022 | True | None | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 | 2022 | True | True | 2 | 2 |
| 123 | 3 | 2022 | False | True | 2 | 0 |
| 123 | 4 | 2022 | False | False | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 5 | 2022 | True | False | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 6 | 2022 | True | True | 2 | 2 |
| 123 | 7 | 2022 | True | True | 3 | 3 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022 | True | True | 4 | 4 |
| 123 | 9 | 2022 | False | True | 4 | 0 |

I thought about first creating the CumSumWithGroups and then creating another column that would take the lag of the CumSumWithGroups when ActivePreviousMonth == True and ActiveInMonth == False
but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it.

Thanks in advance for your time.